# Change lock screen Windows 10 powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm creating a script that when a user is running updates, the workstation locks the screen. The lock screen is a custom JPEG. While updating, the user can't login. After the update is done, the user can login back to their account.

I'm currently using this method for changing the lockscreen:
https://github.com/Sauler/PowershellUtils/blob/master/Set-LockscreenWallpaper/Set-LockscreenWallpaper.ps1

I'm looking now for a way how to get the current lock screen image, because after the update i want to replace the user his lock screen.

Anyone has a method for this?

Comment: Why not invoke [`LockScreen.GetImageStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen.getimagestream) before replacing the users lockscreen, saving the result to a temporary place and then restore it back later?

Answer (score 1):

I created a function after the recommendation of Christian.K

```
function Get-LockscreenWallpaperPath () {
$null = [Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen,Windows.System.UserProfile,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
$Path = [Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen]::OriginalImageFile.AbsolutePath
$Path = $Path -replace '/','\'
return $Path
```

}